# make a total list of a returned map (python)

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda, return

I have the lambda function f:

```
f = lambda x:["a"+x, x+"a"]
```

and I have the list lst:

```
lst = ["hello", "world", "!"]
```

So I did map on the function and the list to get a bigger list but it didn't work as I thought:

```
print map(f, lst)
>>[ ["ahello", "helloa"], ["aworld", "worlda"], ["a!", "!a"] ]
```

As you can see I got lists inside list, but I wanted all of these strings to be in **one** list

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1 = lambda x: "a" + x
f2 = lambda x: x + "a"
l2 = map(f1,lst) + map(f2,lst)
print l2
```

['ahello', 'aworld', 'a!', 'helloa', 'worlda', '!a']

Answer (score 2):

Use [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable):

```
>>> import itertools
>>> f = lambda x: ["a"+x, x+"a"]
>>> lst = ["hello", "world", "!"]
>>> list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(map(f, lst)))
['ahello', 'helloa', 'aworld', 'worlda', 'a!', '!a']
```

Alternative (list comprehension):

```
>>> [x for xs in map(f, lst) for x in xs]
['ahello', 'helloa', 'aworld', 'worlda', 'a!', '!a']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from itertools import chain

f = lambda x:["a"+x, x+"a"]
lst = ["hello", "world", "!"]

print list(chain.from_iterable(map(f, lst)))

>> ['ahello', 'helloa', 'aworld', 'worlda', 'a!', '!a']
```

For documentation see answer from falsetru.

Nice alternative is to use flatten function:

```
from compiler.ast import flatten

f = lambda x:["a"+x, x+"a"]
lst = ["hello", "world", "!"]

print flatten(map(f, lst))
```

The benefit of flatten function: it's can flatten irregular lists:

```
print flatten([1, [2, [3, [4, 5]]]])
>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use list comprehension to flatten out those lists.

```
f = lambda x:["a"+x, x+"a"]
lst = ["hello", "world", "!"]
print [item for items in map(f, lst) for item in items]
```

**Output**

```
['ahello', 'helloa', 'aworld', 'worlda', 'a!', '!a']
```